# C++ arrays sorting/shuffling with specific requirements

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have an array of 20 integers in C++ and I want to shuffle them (random orders).

I also want to sort them in such way that the 10 first numbers are the smallest in ascending order and the rest are just random.

Is there a way to do thi automatically?

Comment: Look in the `<algorithm>` header. There are algorithms for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `<algorithm>` and `<vector>` library?

You can use partial_sort, which does exactly what you want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }

int main () {
  int myints[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
  std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+9);

  std::partial_sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+5, myvector.end());

  std::partial_sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+5, myvector.end(),myfunction);

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not copy the [`std::shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/) code too :P

Comment: @Matin GREAT it does what i want

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is call the `stl` functions `random_shuffle` and `sort`. Both of these functions take iterators, so you can provide just a range of values to each one.

```
int arr[20] = {some values};
sort(arr, arr+20);
random_shuffle(arr+10, arr+20);
```

Comment: Prefer `std::shuffle` with a proper PRNG.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to sort first and then shuffle the remaining elements?

Comment: For a general n maybe, but the OP stated 20 elements so I am not really worried about efficiency.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. He wants the first 10 to be the smallest in the array, so you need to sort them all first, then shuffle arr + 10 to arr + 20.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the fix. I forgot that partial_sort can rearrange the rest of the elements as it pleases.